# Explanation of Linux Kernel FIELD_SIZEOF macro

Tags: c, linux, gcc, macros

I'm learning c99 and after reading about structures I found the following macro in the [Linux Kernel code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h?a=avr32#L53):

```
#define FIELD_SIZEOF(t, f) (sizeof(((t*)0)->f))
```

I.. what? Usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FIELD_SIZEOF(t, f) (sizeof(((t*)0)->f))

struct book {
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%lu\n", FIELD_SIZEOF(struct book, title)); // prints 100
}
```

Here's the expansion (gcc -E)

```
printf("%lu\n", (sizeof(((struct book*)0)->title)));
```

What really baffles me is the `0`. I replaced it with `1`, `2`, `+1`, `-1`, `+999` and `'a'` and `"hello"`, and **it always works**.

There's no comment in the source. I know that `->` is used to access a struct member through a pointer, but how can `((struct book*)0)` be a pointer? How does the macro work?

Comment: It's similar to a common implementation of the standard `offsetof` macro, though that one is a bit trickier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that `sizeof` is calculated by the compiler at compile time. So, the pointer you specify is never actually dereferenced. After all, where an object is located won't change its size. The `sizeof` operator will evaluate its operand purely in terms of types.

So, the address you use is actually irrelevant, but `0` (`NULL`) is a common choice.

Comment: More precisely, the operand of `sizeof` *is not evaluated* (unless it's of a variable-length array type, which doesn't apply here).

Comment: Why are there parentheses in `(t*)0`? Isn't it equivalent to just `t*0` if I get it right?

Comment: @light2yellow: here `t` is the struct type, and hence `(t*)` is typecast to type `t *`.

Comment: @FatalError oh, of course. Now it seems to make much more sense. But how is it possible to do the `->` stuff and why do we need a null pointer cast? How is it possible to just pass the type and get its member's size? I can imagine this operation using a pointer to our struct (allocated dynamically) but not something like this. Will this method work with dynamically allocated structs and struct members too (such as `struct foo {char **bar;};`)? Is this because the information of the needed space is always already inside every struct at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof(((t*)0)->f)
```

works because `sizeof` is defined to not evaluate its argument (there are some exceptions when VLA are involved).