# Dereferencing null pointer valid and working (not sizeof)

Tags: c, pointers, null, dereference

I have recently stumbled upon this macro using address a manipulation trick, in a file dedicated to adding generic doubly linked queues to any `struct`:

```
#define queue_entry(ptr_link, type, listfield) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr_link)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->listfield)))
```

A working example of this macro would be :

```
struct link {
    struct link* next;
    struct link* prev;
};

struct mystruct {
    //...
    struct link chaining;
    //...
}

int main() {
    struct link ex_link;
    struct mystruct *ex_struct = malloc(...);
    ex_struct->chaining = ex_link;
    queue_entry(&ex_link, struct mystruct, chaining); // returns ex_struct
    return 0;
}
```

- Why is `&((type *)0)->listfield` working? I would expect all kinds of compiler errors at this point, due to a null pointer dereferencing. So what happens exactly? I have only seen something similar once before [in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435004/explanation-of-linux-kernel-field-sizeof-macro): 
  `#define FIELD_SIZEOF(t, f) (sizeof(((t*)0)->f))`, which was apparently working [because of `sizeof` being evaluated at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785518/is-dereferencing-null-pointer-valid-in-sizeof-operation). Here, there is no such thing.
- Why the respective casts to `unsigned long` and `char *`? As in, why use two different types, and that are seemingly unrelated to the queue?

Comment: Use offsetof, for everything else there's:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906621/does-struct-name-null-b-cause-undefined-behaviour-in-c11

Comment: @2501: You are right, an application should rely on this. FYI,many implementations define `offsetof` in a similar way (those which use `0x0` as bit-representation of a null pointer).

Comment: Alright, that made it clear, what about the casts though?